# How to read a json-file in nextjs

Tags: json, next.js

I'm just in the progress from migrating a next.js-project (with TypeScript) from the old pages-routing to the new app-routing. Now i try to implement a new feature for my project, which read json-data directly from a file.

I first try to implement code according to the official guide...
https://vercel.com/guides/loading-static-file-nextjs-api-route
... but the guide still based on the old pages-routing

I have also considered the new documentations for data-fetching:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching

I tried to get it to work as follows, while putting the json-file in the public folder (public/data/plz.json):

```
import path from 'path'

async function getData() {
  const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'data/plz.json')
  const res = await fetch(filePath)
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
  return res.json()
}
```

Mistakenly, i used `'use client'` and called the `getData()`-function as follows:

```
export default async function Filter() {
  const plzData = getData()
  const plz = await plzData
...
```

What then happened was that the json file was indeed fetched, but an infinite number of times, the first call with status 200, all others with status 304 (when running with `npm run dev`)

Afterwards I removed the `'use client'` dsfsdf, as this component should run on the server. But the I got an error without any further details: `- error TypeError: fetch failed`

I think, the problem ist now, how to build correctly the path to the json-file.

Any ideas? Or is there even a better way to get json-data?